# Can you add three onClick Listener in a single ImageView using either masking or other means?

Tags: java, android, imageview, onclicklistener

I've been trying since 3 days, I could not yet figure it out so any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: why there is a need for three clicklistener ?

Comment: what is your use case?

Comment: i can rotate an image, so after it stops i need onClickListeners for every segments of the same image...

Comment: Why not just add one listener and call your three things from there?

Comment: well calling things depend on where you click...clicking on specific area does specific thing....

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what "masking" means in this context. You can only have one `OnClickListener` on any `View`. However, that `OnClickListener` can:

- hold three other `OnClickListeners` and call `onClick()` on each of them, or
- otherwise alert everybody who needs to know about the click, such as calling a method on a controller, or posting a message to an event bus, or something

Comment: Yeah , I wanted to know that, one onClick per view..! So I need to get some other way around. Thanks for answering !

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap ImageView in custom class and do whatever you want with it) In particular, you can register this CustomImageView class with any EventBus and create three onEvent() nethods that will listen three different events.

This is realization with GreenRobot EventBus, but you can choose any solution... You can even choose thread on which each event will be handled

```
public class TestImageView extends ImageView {


    public TestImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    public void onEvent(Event1 event) {
        //// some code
    }

    public void onEvent(Event2 event) {
        //// some code
    }

    public void onEvent(Event3 event) {
        //// some code
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean to say, create a CustomView Class for the imageView? Above answers clears though that one Click listener for one View????

Comment: does onEvent work based on the area of the imageView clicked, if not how does those events work ?

Comment: They can work based on area of ImageView. In such a case you need some kind of "scanner" class, object of which listen to touch events in specified area of the screen and post corresponding actions into EventBus.

All you need is instantiate three objects of this "scanner" - each will correspond to separate event. So you will get three separate calls to TestImageView.

Comment: i did get what you r saying....but do you have any links to learn how that stuff works??

Comment: This implementation will get you to deeps of Android View system - so i recommend to start with this Page - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html.Actualy - you should become familiar with Surface, Canvas, etc.

Or maybe you should find more elegant solution for your current task - three separate listeners for ImageView looks wierd))

Comment: thanks for your time! I will finish the task and let you know once i complete that...

Answer (score 1):

a possibile implementation would make use a internal Collection of `View.OnClickListener`. The instance of `OnClickListenerWrapper` is the one that you set to your `ImageView`, and it holds the other `OnClickListener`

```
public static class OnClickListenerWrapper implements View.OnClickListener {

    final List<View.OnClickListener> mListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        synchronized (mListeners) {
            mListeners.add(listener);
        }
    }

    public void remove(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        synchronized (mListeners) {
            mListeners.remove(listener);
        }
    }

    public void clear( ) {
        synchronized (mListeners) {
            mListeners.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        synchronized (mListeners) {
            for (View.OnClickListener l : mListeners) {
                l.onClick(v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not what i m looking for...it''s something the image should implement some specific methods based on the "area" it's been clicked. I know its possible but is there any tried that before?

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean... It is probably possible if you subclass ImageView, override onTouch and check if the touch event intersect the area you are looking for. Do you know already which part of the image you would like to be clickable?

Comment: yeah, there are are 6 parts where one can click to execute different methods... i think your idea might work....i didnt try it yet....did you try anytime before? or can you help me with the code to "determine the part" where the user clicks to execute the required method?